# AWS quicksight report

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to create aws quicksight report using conditional formatting exactly like below: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTxR.png

Answer (score 0):

This is an older Post, answering this for the people who might face similar issue.

If you're referring to the upward and downward arrows, you can do it using conditional filtering.

1. Click on the Visual-Menu, select Conditional Formatting
2. Select the column to which you want to apply conditional formatting
3. If a value is greater than 0 then you need to select an icon and apply color to it

If you want to do it using SQL, you can create a flag (up/down) based on a column in the table and you can use that flag for conditional formatting.